# Fire After Update trigger with respective method only if we update the respective field

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

I have a Handler Class and helper Class.

Calling 3 Different methods from Handler classes.

I want to call those Methods only when the respective fields are changed.

```
public void OnAfterUpdate()
{
    helper.CreateUpdatePhoneNumber(newContacts,oldContacts,oldMap);
    helper.CreateUpdateEmail(newContacts,oldContacts,oldMap);
    helper.UpdateAddress(newContacts,oldContacts,oldMap);
}
```

Can I use the below code for 3 different fields or any possibility to use it like this?

```
Ifchanged (Phonefield)
{
helper.CreateUpdatePhoneNumber(newContacts,oldContacts,oldMap); 
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: if(!TriggerHelper.isMethodExecuted())
        {    
        for(Contact obj:newContacts){
            if(obj.Phone!= oldMap.get(obj.Id).Phone)
            {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to install the [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) library, you can just do:

```
List<Contact> phoneChanged = Select.Field.hasChanged(Contact.Phone)
    .filter(newContacts, oldMap);
```

This library helps you fit your mental model with the collections based approach. Define the collection of records you want to act upon, *then* take action unconditionally on that collection.

Within a loop, a basic comparison would look like:

```
List<Contact> phoneChanged = new List<Contact>();
for (Contact record : newContacts)
{
    if (record.Phone != oldMap.get(record.Id).Phone)
    {
        phoneChanged.add(record);
    }
}
```

With either of the filtered lists above, you would substitute them for `newContacts` in your method call:

```
helper.CreateUpdatePhoneNumber(phoneChanged, oldContacts, oldMap);
```

It's unclear why your method would need both `oldContacts` and `oldMap`, usually you just need the latter. Depending on the internals of that method, you may need to also filter those collections, but only if the logic is convoluted.

Comment: Can i just do thisfor (Contact record : newContacts)
{
    if (record.Phone != oldMap.get(record.Id).Phone)
    {
         helper.CreateUpdatePhoneNumber(newContacts,oldContacts,oldMap);
    }
}

Comment: No, you would need to pass in a filtered list instead of `newContacts`.

Answer (score 0):

The Logic worked

```
   if(!TriggerHelper.isMethodExecuted())
        {    
        for(Contact obj:newContacts){
            if(obj.Phone!= oldMap.get(obj.Id).Phone)
            {
            }
        }
```